# Command npm install is not executed inside container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have this `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3'
services:
  cypress:
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_BASE_URL=https://test.com
      - CYPRESS_USERNAME=user
      - CYPRESS_PASSWORD=password
    entrypoint: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

My `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM cypress/included:13.7.1

WORKDIR /app

# Copy application files
COPY ./app/package*.json ./
COPY ./app .

RUN npm install

# Set the default command to run when the container starts
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Tree is like this :

[image]

Once my container is builded, I connect to it and I can see the file package.json; I run npm install and is working perfect;

Why this npm install is not working during the build of container ?

I tried to comment volumes, in this case the npm install is working, but /node_modules, package-locak.json are visible only in docker container;

Thx in advance;

Comment: Your volume mapping of your host `./app` directory on top of the `/app` directory in the container replaces the container directory with the host directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `volumes:` block in your Compose file overwrites the entire `/app` directory in the image; nothing you do in your Dockerfile will be visible.

I'd generally avoid bind mounts like this.  Since you `COPY` your entire application code into the image (this is a good practice) you can remove the bind mount.  The [`cypress/included` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress/included) also includes a standard `CMD`, so you don't need to override the `CMD` in your Dockerfile or forcibly override `entrypoint:` in the Dockerfile so the container does nothing.

I might change the Dockerfile to:

```bash
FROM cypress/included:13.7.1

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app/package*.json ./

# Run this _before_ the second `COPY` to avoid rerunning package
# installation on non-package changes
RUN npm install

COPY ./app .

# inherit the CMD from the base image
```

And the Compose setup:

```yaml
version: '3.8'  # `3` is read as `3.0`, specify latest 3.x version
services:
  cypress:
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_BASE_URL=https://test.com
      - CYPRESS_USERNAME=user
      - CYPRESS_PASSWORD=password
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    # do not override entrypoint: or set volumes: hiding image code
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, npm is executed, but in fact /node_modules is still missing